# GWT input type won't work

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have been developing small gwt screen with smartwgt components and nearly at the end of the task I found out not a single keyboard buttons are working on any input, I cannot type, cannot do tab between inputs. it was working few days ago while I was in the middle of development. I cannot think of any reason that makes this wont work. Here is the screen, I can only select from dropdown using mouse. Any idea what may be turned on, or canceling or keyboard events? 
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtJIi.jpg)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to be there was a native java method which was initializing a method to hand page keypress which messed up:

```
private static native void initKeyHandler()/*-{
        $wnd.onPageKeyPress = function (event) {}
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to offer a solution without seeing the code, but one possibility is that you added some empty panel on top of your other UI elements, and this panel consumes all user actions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the thing is I can do copy, paste to the input fields, I I can highlight and so forth